# How to log exceptions to a file?

Tags: exception, devexpress, xtrareport

Using [this example](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/401687/web-reporting/general-information-on-web-reporting/application-diagnostics?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T1045614&contactId=A533354#server-side-diagnostics) for my MVC project, I want to log my exception on a file, even without attaching a debugger, when I run my project after publishing it on IIS, not in output window when the project is in debug.

My code is the same as the one presented in the link.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace ServerSide
{
    public class MyLoggerService : DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ClientControls.LoggerService
    {
        public override void Info(string message)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[{0}]: Info: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now, message);
        }
        public override void Error(Exception exception, string message)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[{0}]: Exception occured. Message: '{1}'. Exception Details:\r\n{2}",
                DateTime.Now, message, exception);
        }
    }
}
```

How could I change this code in order to make it log exceptions to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs it, the solution is to add in Error method this code:

```
    string filePath = @"C:\ReportDesigner\server\publish\Exceptions.txt";


    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        writer.WriteLine("Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        writer.WriteLine();

        while (exception != null)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(exception.GetType().FullName);
            writer.WriteLine("Message : " + exception.Message);
            writer.WriteLine("StackTrace : " + exception.StackTrace);

            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
    }
```